# Photo Collage made out of smaller pictures

Tags: mac, photos

Is there an application that can take a bunch of small pictures and convert it to bigger (higher resolution) collage? Ideally it should be a native app that can run on a mac.

Comment: The best programs are unfortunately on Windows.

Comment: @harrymc Picasa can run on Mac OS X as well, so it's not such a major problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take pictures with any photo camera and then make a collage with [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Shape Collage](http://www.shapecollage.com/), and have found it to be excellent. Works with Windows, macs and Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the screensavers shipped with Mac OS X (at least since Leopard) is able to do this with iPhoto Library contents. Impressive, but of little use in your case.

Answer (score 0):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) has a tool (montage) useful to perform such a collage. And yes, there is a mac version too.

A simple sample of [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) and a [more exhaustive sample](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) is on Imagemagick site.
Montage is a command-line tool, e.g.:
`montage '*.jpg' -border 2x2 -background white -geometry -50-50 -tile x3 out.jpg`

You can obtain nice effects simply by following the site examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]